# Can the "M" language be used in VBA to automate transformations?

Tags: excel, vba, powerquery, excel-2016, m

I am using Get and Transform in Excel 2016 where each transform operation lists its M language code. Can that code be somehow used in VBA to automate several transformations within other VBA code?

Comment: related: [What is the M language for?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2891623/what-is-the-m-language-for)

Comment: It says in the stackoverflow blurb http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/m that the language was incorporated into excel, so maybe a few google searches might uncover that interaction

Comment: It is incorporated into Excel and is used with the Get & Transform functions.

Comment: You can use VBA / VB.NET to automate the power query process. thisworkbook.queries is the collection.

Comment: @Jeeped - the M langauge is the coding language used to make Power Queries as far as I know...

Answer (score 0):

Through the power of google I found the msdn refernce for M functions in excel.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt211003.aspx

It appears to be called Power Query now.

Comment: Thanks. I had also used the "power of google" and found the link above but did not find the answer to my question. Can M be used within VBA code to perform transformations?? I am probably missing something obvious and would appreciate any guidance.

Comment: When you say transformations? Do you mean like updating the source of the query or adding in one or two steps? If so, then short answer is no. But the way you would update a queries formula, would be to retrieve the current formula, then to alter it to what you want, then to delete the query and add it again with the new formula as I think the formula property is read only and cannot be changed. But, to create a new query with a new formula is very possible, that's how I do it...